# Historical Figure Identification

Tags: riddle, word, history

The computer at the history museum is on the fritz! When asked about a famous general, all it spit out was

> Clean. 2,000 lbs.

Who did it mean?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Probably

> General Washington - I'm assuming George

Because

> Clean - Washing
>  
>  2,000 - Ton

Comment: You got it! I'll accept it when SE lets me

Comment: @Randal'Thor, it's a US ton :) https://www.metric-conversions.org/weight/short-tons-to-pounds.htm#metricConversionTable

Comment: 1 ton - 2000lbs